# Vertically Aligning Multiple Symbols in Each Row

Tags: equations, align, amsthm

In the following MWE, I want the `\implies` symbols to be aligned, and both `\leq` symbols on each row to be aligned (adding space between everything as necessary).

How can I add `&` symbols in the `align*` code to make this happen?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
|p - q| \leq M
& \implies -M \leq p - q \leq M \\
& \implies q - M \leq p \leq q + M
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

To be clear, I want the output to look like this (just substitute `\leq` for each `<`):

```
|p - q| < M ==>  - M  < p - q <  M
            ==> q - M <   p   < q + M
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the kind of alignment desired you have several options: the `alignat` environment from `amsmath`, an `array`, or to use `\phantom` to add spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
|p - q| \leq M
& \implies -M && \leq p - q && \leq M \\
& \implies q - M && \leq p && \leq q + M
\end{alignat*}

\[
\begin{array}{c@{\ \implies\ }c@{\ \leq\ }c@{\ \leq\ }c}
|p - q| \leq M & -M & p - q &  M \\
& q - M &  p & q + M
\end{array}
\]

\begin{align*}
|p - q| \leq M
& \implies \phantom{q}-M \leq p - q \leq \phantom{q+{}}M \\
& \implies q - M \leq p\phantom{{}-q} \leq q + M
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's how to obtain the alignment required in a comment, using a macro `\centerto` which makes a nice use of `\ooalign`; the macro was defined [here at c.t.t](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/7976c94d7cf9a424/3bfda283f4cf3ee2?lnk=gst&q=amsmath+change+column+alignment#3bfda283f4cf3ee2) by Enrico Gregorio:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\centerto}[2]{% 
  {\ooalign{$\displaystyle\hphantom{#2}$\cr 
     \hidewidth$\displaystyle#1$\hidewidth\cr}}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
|p - q| \leq M
& \implies \centerto{-M}{q-M} \leq p - q \leq \centerto{M}{q+M} \\
& \implies q - M \leq \centerto{p}{p-q} \leq q + M
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your second option provides exactly the option I was looking for.  Thank you!  P.S. Is there any way to achieve a similar result using the `\align` environment?

Comment: @jamaicanworm see the Solution II in my answer (it's the other one).

Comment: @jamaicanworm: sure; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `alignat` environment (also from the `amsmath` package)

[image]

Note that (from the documentation)

> This environment takes one argument, the number of “equation columns”:
>   count the maximum number of &s in any row, add 1 and divide by 2.

In this case, there are 5 `&` in each row, so adding 1 and dividing by 2 gives `{3}` equation columns. Note that I've used `{}` to get correct spacing around the `\leq` symbols

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
|p - q| \leq M & \implies -M    &{}\leq{} & p - q & {}\leq {}& M \\
               & \implies q - M &{}\leq{} & p     & {}\leq {}& q + M
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Here's another option using the `array` environment, but I think Gonzalo's `array` answer gives better spacing

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{*{7}{c}}
            |p - q| \leq M & \implies & -M    &\leq & p - q &\leq & M \\
                           & \implies & q - M &\leq & p     &\leq & q + M
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: As with tohecz's solution, this doesn't work perfectly, since the `p` is not centered between the two `\leq` symbols...

Comment: @jamaicanworm see my edit

Comment: This way, it has quite wrong spacing (too wide). The @GonzaloMedina 's solution is much closer to the correct spacing (as can be seen by comparing his 2nd solution with his 1st and 3rd ones, the 2nd one is a bit wider, but very close to the other ones).

Comment: @tohecz yes, which is why I clearly stated that *Gonzalo's array answer gives better spacing*

Comment: My apologies, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\phantom` to make something "invisible". Just notice the necessary empty brackets `{}` after `+` and before `-`, without them the `+`/`-` sign behaves like "unary operator" and gets different spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
|p - q| \leq M
& \implies \phantom{q}-M \leq p - q \leq \phantom{q+{}}M \\
& \implies q - M \leq p\phantom{{}-q} \leq q + M
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

### Solution II: centered

You can you the `\mathclap` macro from `mathtools` twice to get it centered. I made a command `\mathcenterto` that takes two arguments: 1st to determine the correct width and 2nd to be typeset. See the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% YOU NEED THESE TWO LINES:
\usepackage{mathtools}
\def\mathcenterto#1#2{\mathclap{\phantom{#1}\mathclap{#2}}\phantom{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
|p - q| \leq M
& \implies \mathcenterto{q-M}{-M} \leq p - q \leq \mathcenterto{q+M}{M} \\
& \implies q - M \leq \mathcenterto{p-q}{p} \leq q + M
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But then the `p` is not centered between the two `\leq` symbols...

Comment: I know. It's a matter of taste. You seem to want to have the `\leq` aligned to show the correspondence. This just ephasizes that `p` is the same one in the upper and the lower ineqality.

Comment: I added Solution II that makes it 1) centered 2) with the origninal `align*` envrionment.